# Geometry node: mirror position of object

Tags: geometry-nodes, mirror, mirror-modifier

I would like to fake the "mirror" modifier in Geometry Node (Blender 3.0) except that I only want to keep the mirrored object (to parent it to some bones), but I can't find how to do. All transforms in GeometryNodes seem to be in the local space, while I need to change the global position of the vertices.

[image]

For now, I created a first curve object called "WingModel" (on the left) that I can freely edit (I want to keep non-destructive editing). Then, WingLeft is just a Geometry Node taking the geometry of the WingModel using Object Info, that I position as I like. Now, I want to design WingRight to be the mirror of the WingLeft, ideally using Geometry Nodes.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result in the following way:

1. First move the transformation (position, rotation) of the right wing to the node `Transform` in the geometry nodes.
2. For the left wing, use the vector node `Reflect` and feed the resulting vector into `Set Position` to create a flip on the X/Y axes.

It is also advisable to set the origin point of the object to the place where you want your center of rotation to be, because this makes the result more controllable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice trick! (I could not find reflect, so I used math vector > multiply > (-1,1,1)) But I still have a few questions 1) Oh, this `set position` sets the position of each vertex relative to the object center? I though it was setting the position of the center of the object, now it's clearer ^^ 2) Do you know how I could do the same, but when the center is an absolute point and not the common origin of both objects? Sometimes, I may like to move my object globally (without using the transform operation) as it's much easier to use when moving multiple objects.

Comment: I explained in another comment how to mirror the object relative to the absolute XZ plane.

Answer (score 4):

To complete on the answer of quellenform, here are some variations depending on what you want to do:

## Mirror: use object as center

When using quellenform's solution, the mirrored object is not moved when the parent object is moved. A first solution is to parent one object relative to the other. The other solution is to use the `location` property to translate appropriately the object.

[image]

## Mirror: use world YZ plane as center

If one wants to use the absolute world center to mirror the object, you can do something like that on the mirrored object:

[image]

Note that for this to work, you need to be sure that your second object has position `(0,0,0)`. Here is a more complicated setup that also work when the second object is not at position `(0,0,0)`, and that also works when the object is scaled with a **positive scale** (see also [Blender: get/set absolute location of object in Geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262780/blender-get-set-absolute-location-of-object-in-geometry-nodes/262781#262781)).

[image]

Demo:

[image]